# Using John the Ripper for Blockchain.info second password

Tags: passwords, hash, password-cracking, john-the-ripper

Is there a way to use JtR for Blockchain.info's (v2) secondary password?

I already tried the `blockchain2john.py` file, and it does not ask for primary password (which I know already) so it is going to look for the one I know, instead of secondary one that I don't.

I have tried `btcrecover` before, but I need to use some JtR features for this.

Any help is appreciated!

This is the output I get from `blockchain2john.py`:

```
wallet.aes.json:$blockchain$v2$5000$8272$...
```